# Is there any way to add a letter to the bottom left area of a UIKeyboardType.NumberPad?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

The `UIKeyboardType.NumberPad` looks like this:

[image]

What I want it to look like is this:

[image]

Is there a way to overlay a view in just that corner when the keyboard is up to add this single key? Is this possible with Swift 4?

The reason I want to do this is for easy ISBN number input for users, and some ISBN numbers (10 digits) have an X in them.

Comment: probably not possible, you're going to most likely have to create a custom one I think

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to modify the keyboard and any attempt to position a button in the correct spot will be a hack you want to avoid.

Probably the cleanest solution is to create a toolbar and set the toolbar as the text field's `inputAccessoryView`. On the toolbar, add a button for your `X` and maybe some other buttons such as a keyboard dismiss button, a Next button, or a Done button, etc.